# How do you disable git osxkeychain helper?

Tags: git

I have git installed with homebrew, which includes the osxkeychain helper. It used to be that, to enable the helper, you had to run `git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain`, but it seems to use the OS X keychain now even though I haven't used this configuration (I checked my .gitconfig to be sure). I actually even tried deleting the`git-credential-osxkeychain` executable, but git still somehow is saving my credentials in my keychain. I've worked around it for the moment by locking my keychain file, but I'm hoping to find a more elegant solution so I can store other passwords in my keychain. Thanks!